# How to transform Dataset<Tuple2<String,DeviceData>> to Iterator<DeviceData>

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-dataset

I have `Dataset<Tuple2<String,DeviceData>>` and want to transform it to `Iterator<DeviceData>`.

Below is my code where I am using `collectAsList()` method and then getting `Iterator<DeviceData>`.

```
Dataset<Tuple2<String,DeviceData>> ds = ...;
List<Tuple2<String, DeviceData>> listTuple = ds.collectAsList();

ArrayList<DeviceData> myDataList = new ArrayList<DeviceData>();
for(Tuple2<String, DeviceData> tuple : listTuple){
    myDataList.add(tuple._2());
}

Iterator<DeviceData> myitr = myDataList.iterator();
```

I cannot use `collectAsList()` as my data is huge and it will hamper performance. I looked into Dataset API but couldn't get any solution. I googled it but couldn't find any answer. Can someone please guide me? If the solution is in java that will be great. Thanks.

**EDIT :**

`DeviceData` class is simple javabean. Here is printSchema() output for ds.

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- deviceData: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- deviceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sNo: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly extract `DeviceData` from `ds` instead of collecting and building again.

**Java:**

```
Function<Tuple2<String, DeviceData>, DeviceData> mapDeviceData =
    new Function<Tuple2<String, DeviceData>, DeviceData>() {
      public DeviceData call(Tuple2<String, DeviceData> tuple) {
        return tuple._2();
      }
    };

Dataset<DeviceData> ddDS = ds.map(mapDeviceData) //extracts DeviceData from each record
```

**Scala:**

```
val ddDS = ds.map(_._2) //ds.map(row => row._2)
```